# Option select the Javascript value

Tags: javascript, forms, select, html-table

The option value can't be selected because the value is getting from the Javascript

For Example:

```
           <td>Nationality
            <select id="nationality" name ="nationality" >
            <option selected="true" value="Malaysia"> Malaysia </option>
            </select>
            <script language="javascript">
            nationality("nationality");
            </script>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

How can I keep the Malaysia value because after I refresh it will return back to "Please select"...

Answer (score 0):

Put selected  in option tag to select the value by default.

```
<td>Nationality
        <select id="nationality" name ="nationality" >
        <option selected="true" value="Malaysia" selected> Malaysia </option>
        </select>
        <script language="javascript">
        nationality("nationality");
        </script>
        </td>
        </tr>
```

I hope this works.